# MongoDB javascript ingest JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a big JSON string that is 10 records, each with their own properties.  I need to ingest them into my MongoDB with Javascript.  I'm basically useless with Javascript, and google has largely failed me.  The JSON looks like this, basically:

```
[{"ID":1,"Name":"bob"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Jim"}]
```

Obviously a lot more, but that's the basic structure.  How would one, using Node.js for example, import that into Mongo?  Mongo's documentation largely only covers their shell commands, but those dont' directly translate into Javascript.

Comment: Dont know how you look at documentation, but i'd say pretty badly. Because this [mongodb documentation with nodejs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html) explains it pretty good...

Comment: @WilomGfx exactly the doc of mongo is pretty good check out and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a bulk insert like so:

```
var MyObject = mongoose.model('MyObject', MyObjectSchema);

var objectsArray = [/* array of MyObject objects */];

MyObject.collection.insert(objectsArray, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i normally use mongoose plugin driver, to save such a document , define the schema first, at a glance your schema seems to  have two fields ID and Name, with id custom. It is custom because mongodb uses it own id, to change this use auto-increment-plugin. So after you define your schema, mongodb will only save or insert a object if the fields match the schema.

```
db.collection.insert(
   <document or array of documents>,
   {
     writeConcern: <document>,
     ordered: <boolean>
   }
)
```

The above is the format for a document insertion.document   document or array   A document or array of documents to insert into the collection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: checkout the docs for more information on schema and insertions.